# How do SQLite batch operations compare to transactions in Android?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

What differences are there between the following two?

- Using explicit transactions with [beginTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) and [endTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29)
- Using a batch of [content provider operations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html)

Comment: You cannot compare those two... ContentProvider not allways is implemented with Sqlite database... Next, is up to you how you implement batch operation in CP fx you can use transaction there(afaik default implementation is naive but check source)